# DNN install always hangs

Tags: installation, dotnetnuke, failed-installation

I must have done over 100 installs of DNN (dnnsoftware.com) now, and I have never seen the "wizard" complete correctly. It always hangs at 28%. Upgrades usually hang at the 53% level.

This appears to be a user interface fault, because if I wait long enough - how long? - I can navigate to the site and all is working perfectly. If I don't wait long enough, some part of the installation process restarts and gives me a site without a superuser account.

The installation process does not appear to have been adequately tested. Anyone know how to get the "wizard" to complete correctly?

Comment: I've done about the same amount of installations, and nearly all of them (say 98%) completed installation with the wizard just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't experienced this high of failure rate with the installation or upgrade.

In order to diagnose the problem, do an upgrade.  Before applying the upgrade, set the AutoUpgrade key in the web.config to "false".  Then initiate the upgrade by going to:

[baseurl]/install/install.aspx?mode=upgrade.

Instead of the simple progress bar, you will get a detailed report of the extensions and items being installed or upgraded.

Before installing, make sure your file permissions are set appropriately on the website folder and you follow all of the steps as per the [installation guidelines](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/how-to-install-dotnetnuke).

Also, if it turns out the issue is timeouts during the install due to a slow server, try increasing the execution timeout in the web.config in the `<httpRuntime>` node.  The default executionTimeout is "1200" which is 20 minutes.  if your upgrade or installation is taking longer, increase the value.